# RxJS return array of values from mergeMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an observable stream. The first operator is a mergeMap that returns an array of observables. I then have to have a second mergeMap to get the final values from the first mergeMap's return. I feel this second mergeMap should be unnecessary, but cannot find a way around it.

Example:

```
source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => [of(1), of(2), of(3)]),
  mergeMap((val) => val)
)
```

This is ultimately what I have. The second mergeMap only exists to subscribe to the output of the first. Without it, my output is the observable (i.e. `of(1)` instead of the actual value 1). Is there a way around having this second mergeMap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [merge](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge) function inside your `mergeMap` operator to merge all observables inside your array of Observables into one single observable that will emit when any underlying observable emits.

The snippet for this would be:

```
source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => merge(...[of(1), of(2), of(3)])),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the first `mergeMap` is applied to the array, whatever array.

In other words

```
source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => ['a', 'b', 'c']),
)
```

emits firtst `a` then `b` then `c` and then completes.

So, in your case you need the second `mergeMap` to flatten the Observables emitted.

As an alternative approach, if it makes sense in your case, you could use `forkJoin` rather than `mergeMap`. Something like this

```
source$.pipe(
  forkJoin([of(1), of(2), of(3)]),
)
.subscribe(console.log) // '1' '2' '3'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, however in this case I want values to be emitted concurrently, I don't want to wait for all to complete. See tomcek112's answer